# Centered inline block sibling stretch to the remaining width

Tags: html, css

I have 3 inline block elements;

The middle one is centered. I would like to stretch the others to take the remaining width container.

This is what I tried so far:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.line {
  border: dashed 1px #C7C9C7;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 38%;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr class="line" />
  <div class="content">This is a text</div>
  <hr class="line" />
</div>
```

How can I have the same result even if middle width will change?

Comment: This is just an example or you really just want to place a dotted line at the sides of the text ?

Comment: is really a dotted line, and would be better to have it aligned aligned also vertically. Kind of <hr> with text in the middle is what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: why don't you just use `:pseudo` elements `:before` and `:after` to make the border instead?

Comment: can you post an answer with your proposal please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` on the `.container` to get the wanted output : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buwhny1e/7/)

```
    .container{
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: yellow;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;

        align-items: center;
    }
```

If you change the text in the middle, it will keep it centered and stretch the two others to take the remaining width of the container.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, is there a way to keep the dotted line same as before?

Comment: you're welcome, I edited my answer